# RMarkDown - symbol * in kable with condition

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to put the symbol * inside the table. So far I manged to put symbols in the header and in the first column, but not inside the table. To be precise I would like to mark all values in a certain row or in a certain column that are less than a fixed value. Can you help?
Here's a reproducible example:

```
 dt<- mtcars[,1:6]
 dt_footnote <- dt
 names(dt_footnote)[2] <- paste0(names(dt_footnote)[2], 
                                    footnote_marker_symbol(1))
 row.names(dt_footnote)[4] <- paste0(row.names(dt_footnote)[4], 
                                    footnote_marker_alphabet(1))


 kable(dt_footnote, align = "c", 
        escape = F) %>%
     kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
     footnote(alphabet = "Footnote A; ",
               symbol = "Footnote Symbol 1; ",
               alphabet_title = "Type II: ", symbol_title = "Type III: ",
               footnote_as_chunk = T)
```

Here's my attempt but it doesnt work:

```
dt$disp<-ifelse(dt$disp<170,paste0(dt$disp,
                  footnote_marker_symbol(1)),dt$disp)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your example, as it throws and error when it runs. However this example should work

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

dt <- mtcars[,1:6]

dt <- dt %>% 
  mutate(disp = case_when(
    disp < 150 ~ paste0(as.character(disp), "*"),
    TRUE ~ paste0(disp)
  ))

kable(dt, align = "c", 
      escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  footnote(alphabet = "Footnote A; ",
           symbol = "Footnote Symbol 1; ",
           alphabet_title = "Type II: ", symbol_title = "Type III: ",
           footnote_as_chunk = T)
```

[image: example output]